# What does 'viz.' means?

Tags: word-meaning

I recently came across the following sentence:

> Matter can exist in 3 states viz. solid, liquid and gas.

I am not sure what the word 'viz.' means can anyone explain me it's meaning and usage?

Comment: You could easily have looked this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viz.):

> The abbreviation viz. (or viz without a full stop) is short for the Latin videlicet, which itself is a contraction of the Latin phrase videre licet, meaning "it is permitted to see". It is used as a synonym for "namely", "that is to say", "to wit", "which is", or "as follows". It is typically used to introduce examples or further details to illustrate a point. For example: "all types of data viz. text, audio, video, pictures, graphics, can be transmitted through networking"